# How can I copy all *.xls files from a remote server, within different directories?

Tags: shell, rsync, scp

The remote server holds a very large number of files in differing directory depths. From the server, I would like to extract and copy all these *.xls files to my local desktop.

I am able to find all the files using:

```
find . -name '*.xls'
```

This correctly produces a list with file-paths all the file names I need.

I am also aware that scp may need to be used, which I can do for individual files:

```
scp user@server:path/path/path.../file.xls /Desktop
```

I have tried:

```
find . -name '*.xls' -exec cp --parents \{\} /Desktop \;
```

But this does not work, because it is from a remote directory to local.

I need to keep the file-paths leading to the files so that the directory structure remains the same.

I hope my question is clear enough, I am very inexperienced, thanks.

I currently have:

```
rsync -a --prune-empty-dirs --include '*ping.xls' --exclude '*pattern*' --exclude '*pattern2*' --exclude '*pattern3*' --exclude '...and_so_on*' ./remote_server ./Local_Desktop
```

Is there a more elegant way to exclude everything except that which is in the include pattern? Currently it is just rsync-ing everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having tried:

```
rsync -a --prune-empty-dirs --include */ --include '*ping.xls' --exclude '*' ./server ./target
```

And many other combinations, I discovered the importance of these:
    ''

Works with:

```
rsync -a --prune-empty-dirs --include '*/' --include '*ping.xls' --exclude '*' ./server ./target/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use rsync instead. Do not setup rsync but manually call it whenever you want. Give top level folder of the src machine and give the file pattern.

Eg. 
`rsync -a --include=*.xls me@srcmachine:/opt/topfolder /tmp`

Comment: Thank you for your response, I just tried that from my local directory. It failed stating : rsync: link_stat "Desktop/*.xls" failed: No such file or directory?
I am looking to take the files from the remote server and place them in my local directory.

Comment: can you try the edited command.
Also see http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_rsync.htm which will help you figure out the right command.

Comment: I tried the edited command, was prompted for server password, now it states: skipping directory results. I have skimmed that page you suggested with options, should I put -R next to --include? I don't think it is looking inside all the directories perhaps? Thanks for your patience.